# How to access a top-level module from deep within nested modules in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's imagine:

```rb
module A
   class ClassA
      def MethodA
         puts "I am the original."
      end
   end
end

module B
   module C
      module D

      end
   end
end
```

Now, say you can only control what happens inside `module D` (imagine your code is getting required in there), but from here you want to access or even extend `module A` or `class ClassA`.

If you attempt:

```rb
module A
   class ClassA
      def MethodA
         puts "You have been overridden!"
      end
   end
end
```

...then later when `A::ClassA.MethodA` is called, you'll still get "I am the original." This is because all you've really done is defined a new module called `A` deep inside `module D`.

How can you write code that will access/extend the true `module A` at the top level, from deep inside `module D`?

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: When asking a question it helps if you frame it in terms of what you've done, not some hypothetical person ("you") that _might_ do it that way. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the answer to this. You need to prepend `A` with `::` to access the top level explicitly.

```rb
module ::A
   class ClassA
      def MethodA
         puts "You have been overridden!"
      end
   end
end
```

Now, `MethodA` has truly been overriden and will output "You have been overridden!"

Comment: Note: `MethodA` is not overridden, it is *overwritten*. The original is gone.